# How to include a specific version of jar into Uber jar?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

When building my project, maven downloads dependencies spark-avro, versions 1.8.2 and 2.4.3, and it packages the wrong one.

In my pom.xml file I only have spark-avro version 2.4.3, the 1.8.2 is a transitive dependency from somewhere else.

How do I specify the concrete version to be included into the uber jar? I tried doing:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-assembly</finalName>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>org.apache.http</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>org.shaded.apache.http</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>com.alcon.salesforce.etl:alcon-salesforce-etl</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>com/alcon/etl/glue/common/**</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <includes>
this --------------------->   <include>org.apache.avro:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.3</include>
                                <include>com.alcon.etl.common:*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <shadedClassifierName>assembly</shadedClassifierName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

as you can see at the top, I wrote the specific version of spark-avro there, which is `org.apache.avro:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.3` but I messed up somewhere, because when I extract the contents of the resulting jar, there is no spark there.

What is the proper syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the wrong place. Maven first consolidates the dependencies to a list (in which every artifact appears in only one version). Your `<include>` is just a filter on this list.

So probably, Maven does not choose the dependency you expect when it mediates the transitive dependencies. But I cannot say for sure because I don't have your `dependency:tree`.